# OpenVPN client connect script -Exclusive Address Range-

Tags: vpn, openvpn, bash-scripting

I currently have a client-connection script which sends out an email when clients connect (off course).

It only includes a few lines to:
- End the script so as not to send an email notification based on a few $trusted_ips

But other than this, it will email notify for every other client that connects.

My current goal is: I would like to be able to force the notification ONLY for a specific Address-Range, eg: 192.168.2-20.

All others can be ignored.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be appreciated! This task was handed down, after someone else built the original script.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Keep in mind this site is not a script writing service. You will get help sooner (or at all) if you let us modify something you already have. Pasting your current script is a good start (you may want to obfuscate public IPs etc.). Also tell us what you have tried so far. [Edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1126042/edit) and add this information.

Comment: You really need to post what you have.